# subscribe to a knockout observable for a child property and call a parent method in a binding context in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, typescript

I have this `TypeScript` class

```
export class MyItem {
    public name: any;
    public active: any;

    constructor(private root: MyViewModel, public id: number, name, active) {
        this.name = ko.observable<string>(name);
        this.active = ko.observable<bool>(active);

        this.active.subscribe(() => {
            root.Update(this);
        });
    }
}
```

It is being used like this below where there is a binding between `checked` and the `active` observable property on the input checkbox, this is within a `foreach` binding context for `Items` which is a property on the parent `MyViewModel`.

```
<div class="row" data-bind="visible: ItemsExist" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="item-list" data-bind="foreach: Items">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active" />
                    <span data-bind="text: name, css: { disabled: !active() }"></span>
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Delete" data-bind="click: $parent.Delete.bind($parent)" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I change this `MyItem` class so that I can pass the `$parent` context to the subscribed event on the `active` observable of each item, without having to pass a reference to `MyViewModel` in the constructor?

but also compile in the TypeScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since realised that the `Update` method on the parent `MyViewModel` did not require any reference to the parent to do it's work, so I have moved it to the `MyItem` class, which fixes my problem.

I still haven't seen a way to do what I originally asked without passing a reference of the parent though, even if it is through some `init` method instead of the `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `MyItem` subscribing for changes on its own `active` property in order to inform a third-party entity, `MyViewModel`, when changes occur.  The dilemma is that `MyItem` doesn't really know exactly who the third-party is.

Instead, you can simply have `MyViewModel` subscribe to the `active` property on `MyItem` itself, since `MyViewModel` is the one that cares about the changes and already has a reference to the item.